# Assigning a value to the primary field in code fails

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom entity named **eld_timereg**. This entity has an attribute named **eld_name** (which is the primary field). Records are created in a generic handler (after pushing a button in the ribbon). I'm using late binding.

```
var myService = ...;
var t = new Entity( "eld_timereg" );

t["field1"] = "abc";
.
.
.
t["eld_name"] = GenerateAnUniqueStringCode("ZXC"); 
// returns something like ZXC-16398-T1VC

return myService.Create(t);
```

The record is created without any error. Checking the entity in SSMS, the value is blank although it is a required field.

What is happening here?

Comment: Do you have any plugins registered against that entity? Presumably you have checked the value returned by GenerateAnUniqueStringCode("ZXC") is as you expect?

Comment: No, it is handled in javascript. Clicking a button in the ribbon fires a javascript which is calling a generic handler. Return value is as expected. If I set a breakpoint on the line where the record is created and checking the entity attributes I see a valid value. Executing the creation of the record goes without errors. A record is create in the database except for the eld_name field which is blank.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. You put me on the right track James. Thank you for that. The **eld_name** attribute was overwritten in the plug-in (I forgot). Here it should be filled with some information. This was going wrong and always returned a null.